# Generic DAO with JPA and strategy pattern for ordering/sorting

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dao

I'm working on an update of my implementation of GenericDao with strategy pattern for ordering/sorting.

I used to rely on hibernate API and i'd like to update it with JPA API directly.

```
public interface GenericDao<T extends BaseEntity<T, PK>, PK extends Serializable> {

    long countAll(MyQuery query);

    T create(T newInstance);

    T find(PK id);

    List<T> findAll();

    List<T> find(MyQuery query, SearchStrategy searchStrategy);

    T update(T transientObject);

    void delete(PK id);

}
```

And my SearchStrategy interface:

```
import org.hibernate.Criteria;

public interface SearchStrategy {

    void apply(Criteria criteria);

}
```

If we pay attention to SearchStrategy, the Criteria type **is a hibernate one**.
I got implementation for SearchStrategy (OrderingStrategy, PagingStrategy...)

In thos implementations, I used to call:

```
criteria.setFirstResult(..);
criteria.setMaxResults(..);
```

and

```
criteria.addOrder(Order..);
```

It seems i can't use anymore that pattern with JPA API, as in this specification ordering is done on CriteriaQuery, and paging on TypedQuery which result from CriteriaQuery.

```
CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(entityClass);
criteriaQuery.orderBy()
TypedQuery typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
typedQuery.setMaxResults()
```

Do you see any workaround, or should i have to resign myself to forget strategy pattern for this case ?

Comment: How about using strategy with 2 entry points? The first one with `CreteriaQuery` and the second with `TypedQuery`.

Comment: That would work, it's adding a 2nd level to strategy. Only cons i see is we'll end with two calls.

Comment: Other solution would be to make my strategy method getting criteriaQuery in entry and giving back TypedQuery in result. But it makes a kind of dependency and i would not be able to join different Strategies anymore.

Comment: You can create some kind of "strategy manager" and first apply criteria strategies and then typedQuery strategies but it probably will be ugly.